# How to add a dependency for a target

Tags: makefile, android-source, build-system

How to add a shared library (let it be `libXYZ.so`) as a dependency for a `LOCAL_MODULE` target, when `libXYZ.so` does not link to the target directly.

How to make sure build system first builds the dependency(`libXYZ.so`) and then execute commands for `LOCAL_MODULE` from a `Android.mk`

This is required because in my build, the dependency (`libXYZ.so`) it self is not used but a symlink with different name is used. (`libABC.so  -> libXYZ.so`). The symlink is generated after the shared library is created, as part of `LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the library to the prerequisite list:

```
LOCAL_MODULE: libXYZ.so
```

but then you must trust the rule that builds the library also builds the symlink. It would be safer to make the symlink itself a target, make the symlink a prereq of the module, and make the library a prereq of the symlink.

Comment: I have multilib build and symlinks were created using post install comand. As you said there is no gurantee that the links will be created. How can I create a target that create symlinks. I'm unable to figure out how to do that in way that works on 32 bit and multilib builds.

Comment: Do you know how to create symbolic links *without* Make (e.g. `ln -d libXYZ.so libABC.so`)? Do you wish to write a makefile that will work under multiple operating systems?